# Infinite loop with only one correct solution

Tags: c++

Code running on infinite loop when I enter values > 3.

Also shows only one correct solution of the two entered in case the input is `arr = [1,0,3,4]`.

Solution should be: `{1,3}` and `{0,4}`

```
void find_sum (){

    int i , j , k, *arr, size , target;
    cout << "Enter size of array" <<endl;
    cin >> size;
    arr = new int[size];

    cout << "Enter array elements " << endl;
    for( k = 0 ; k < size ; k++){

        cin >> arr[k];
    }
    cout << "Enter your target " << endl;
    cin >> target;

    i = 0 ;
    j = size - 1;
    while (i < j ){

        if(arr[i] + arr[j] == target )
            cout << "Solution :" << arr[i] <<" " << arr[j] <<endl;
        if ( arr[i] + arr[j] < target )
            i++;
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] > target )
            j--;
    }

}

int main()
{
    find_sum();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add your main() method. Are you calling find_sum() twice? Creating two TwoSumTwoPointer objects?

Comment: int main()
{
    TwoSumTwoPointer ptr;

    ptr.find_sum();
} //This is the main method which has only one TwoSumTwoPointer object!

Comment: And can you please confirm you're not calling `find_sum` from the constructor?

Comment: I removed the class.

Comment: i got the correct answer now without using break.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you make the assumption that your array `arr` is sorted, because everytime you test a solution and the sum is too low, you increase `i`. That is equivalent to taking the next element in the list, assuming that it is bigger.

> if ( arr[i] + arr[j] < target )
>          i++;

In addition, if your sum is equal to target, you output the solution, but never change `i` and `j`. They stay the same and the loop keeps going. That's why you only get one solution. But be aware that your code will crash, after `i` gets over the size of your array or `j` smaller than 0. You should add this condition to your while-loop.